# UITableViewCell accessoryType UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark repeating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with multiple selections allowed, However for some reason when I scroll the UITableView the selections I have made with UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark repeat as I scroll.

This is the code that I am using

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [sortedMachineNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

// In a xib-based application, navigation from a table can be handled in -tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [selectedMachinesMArray addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    NSUInteger index = [selectedMachinesMArray indexOfObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    if (index!=NSNotFound) {
        [selectedMachinesMArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
}
```

Comment: "However for some reason..." The reason is cell reuse. Do a search for "checkmark repeating" and you will find many answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cellforIndexAtPath do a check for the current state of the cell and change the value of the accesory type, like this:

```
if(marked)
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Comment: what is the best practice for marked? should I just create a completely seperate array with T/F for each UITableViewCell in the UITableView?

Comment: OKay I just did this, created an array the same length as the UITableView set every value in the array to false then when there is a selection or deselection i make that value in the array true or false depending.

Comment: @HurkNburkS That's correct, i have this issues in the beginning, for graphically aspect you could use "WillDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath" P.D if you find my answer useful, could you upvoteme?